# Static Image. Does not move with the page size

Tags: html, css, bigcommerce

I dont have any HTML or CSS experience, so pretty much coding illiterate.

The issue I am having is the Paypal logo that I have inserted on my Bigcommerce site, stays static in the same position as the Homepage. So if I am on a product page it creates a gap between the last line of the page and paypal logo.

http://www.mariamseddiq.com/ -> Paypal logo is in the correct position
http://www.mariamseddiq.com/bridal/ -> theres a big gap between the last line of this page and the botton of the page.

Heres the Footer code:

```
<div id="ContainerFooter">
    <div class="Center">
        <div id="FooterUpper">

            <div class="Column">%%Panel.FooterCategoryList%%</div>
            <div class="Column">%%Panel.SideShopByBrand%%</div>
                            <div class="Column">%%Panel.HomeRecentBlogs%%</div>
            <div class="Column NewsletterColumn">
                %%Panel.SideNewsletterBox%%
                %%Panel.SocialLinks%%
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Footer">
            %%Panel.PagesMenu%%
            <p>Copyright %%GLOBAL_Year%% %%GLOBAL_StoreName%% : %%SNIPPET_SitemapLink%%</p>
```

https://store-mc6v042j.mybigcommerce.com/product_images/uploaded_images/paypal-logo-transparent1.png "style="width: 150px; margin-left:750px;position:absolute; top:2100px;">
                
                %%GLOBAL_AllPricesAreInCurrency%%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css changes :

```
position:relative; top:-90px;
```

try this , i meant in both the pages

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the combination of `position:absolute;` and `top:2100px`.  The absolute attribute tells the browser that the item you are positioning will be positioned in a fixed position relative to it's parent.  The `top:2100px` tells it to position it 2100 pixels from the top of the parent.  Instead of positioning it this way try to position it within a box (such as a div) below the element where you want it to display.

Edit:  Just by using the Chrome browser tools I disabled both of those css elements and the logo appears where it should.  Try just removing `position:absolute;top:2100px;`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, you have 2 line break `<br>` and on image you have style `position:absolute; top:2100px`. Just remove these two line breaks, and also  style `position:absolute; top:2100px`. and place `margin-top` to fix the position.

```
<br>
<br> 
<img src=" https://store-mc6v042j.mybigcommerce.com/product_images/uploaded_images/paypal-logo-transparent1.png " 
style="width: 150px; margin-left:750px;position:absolute; top:2100px;">
```

Change it to

```
<img src=" https://store-mc6v042j.mybigcommerce.com/product_images/uploaded_images/paypal-logo-transparent1.png "
style="width: 150px; margin-left:750px; margin-top: -50px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative` to the footer div and set the `top:2100px` from the image to `top:15px` or what else you like.